# Maven fails to compile QuestDB from source with 'ambiguous reference to Record'

Tags: java, maven, questdb

I've been running QuestDB from docker, but to try latest version from master, I followed documentation on GitHub but cannot build from source. The output from the console when I try run any maven commands (`mvn clean test` or `build`) looks like:

```
[INFO] QuestDB core 5.0.6-SNAPSHOT ........................ FAILURE [  7.103 s]
[INFO] JMH benchmarks for QuestDB 1.0 ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] QuestDB 5.0.6-SNAPSHOT ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.192 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-13T15:14:10+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project questdb: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/fmay/proj/qdb/questdb/core/src/main/java/io/questdb/griffin/engine/functions/SymbolFunction.java:[50,39] error: reference to Record is ambiguous
...
```

I'm trying to build using latest Mac os 11.1.

Comment: The error is not from maven.  That is a Java compile error.  You need to import the correct Record class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QuestDB needs to be built with Java 11, check which version is running with

```
java -version
```

If you have something different and you use homebrew, you can [use brew to install openJDK 11](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/openjdk@11) with

```
brew install openjdk@11
```